# Azure policy - liquid template - convert milliseconds to formatted date

Tags: azure-management-api, liquid-template

How can I convert milliseconds date to formatted date.
I tried the following :

```
<set-body template="liquid">
    {                                           
        "date" : "{{ "1610924400000" | Date: "MM/dd/yyyy" }}"
    }    
</set-body>
```

But it prints :

> {"date": "1610924400000"}

Is it possible ? How can i do this pls ?

Comment: Use `{{ "1610924400000" | date: "%m/%d/%Y" }}`

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: You may need to covert from millsecs to seconds i.e. `1610924400` instead of `1610924400000`.

Comment: Doesn't work either :/

Answer (score -1):

According to a an answer on the Microsoft Q&A site, converting from a Unix timestamp is not supported...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1154832/convert-unix-timestamp-to-human-readable-date-usin

> Simple conversions like below works with liquid template however, for unix time (Epoch timestamp), it seems there is no way. The reason is that we use dotliquid nuget package and that package does not support this specific conversion.
> Reference: https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/issues/322
> Feel free to leave your feedback at aka.ms/apimwish so that other users who are in need to similar feature can upvote it and PG can take it forward.

So I guess the only solution for now would be to convert the timestamp to another date format before giving it to the template...

Comment: It does not work

Comment: So sorry, you're right, regular liquid templates use Python style date formatting, but for LogicApps, it uses .NET date formatting by default.

Your code does work in a Ruby styled Liquid template, it seems to only be a problem with dotliquid.